# Highlight comments made by registered users of the site

Tags: comments, templates, css, conditional-tags, registered

How can I highlight comments that have been made by registered users of my blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments that are left by registered users are given the class "byuser" - so you can create a style in your theme's stylesheet to point out these comments.  Something like:

```
.commentlist li.byuser {
        background:#FF0000;
}
```

That would make the background of users' comments red (insert a more appropriate color).

If you are not using a custom theme, I'd recommend creating a child theme to do this.